# Get bytedata data in string

Tags: java, string, byte, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

```
private static int readAndWriteInputStream( final InputStream is, final OutputStream outStream ) throws IOException {
    final byte[] buf = new byte[ 8192 ];
    int read = 0;
    int cntRead;
    while ( ( cntRead = is.read( buf, 0, buf.length ) ) >=0  )
    {
        outStream.write(buf, 0, cntRead);
        read += cntRead;
    }
    outStream.write("\n".getBytes());
    return read;
}
```

Before outStream.write(buf, 0, cntRead); i want to get every single line(read from input text) file into a String .Is it possible to get this byte data into a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply:

```
String s = new String(buf, 0, cntRead);
```

Or with a charset not to use the default one:

```
String s = new String(buf, 0, cntRead, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: That did it . I can really be stupid at times. That thing never came across my mind. Again a big thanks

Comment: Absolutely, I did not know this constructor.

Answer (score 2):

A better approach would be to use a [proper String constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20int,%20int)):

```
String s = new String(buf, 0, cntRead);
```

This way you avoid an unnecessary array copy.

Also in case if there's a possibility that data encoding is different from your platform's default one you have to use [a constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20int,%20int,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) which takes a `Charset` as an additional parameter.